# Servlet getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher shows attributes in url line

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have built a small servlet with two jsp files and a controller.

This is the `login.jsp` :

```
<body>
    <section class="loginform cf">
    <form name="login" action="controller/login" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
        accept-charset="utf-8">
        <ul>
            <li><label for="username">Username</label> <input type="text"
                name="username" ></li>
            <li><label for="password">Password</label> <input
                type="password" name="password" ></li>
            <li><input type="submit" value="Login"></li>
        </ul>
    </form>

    <form  action="http://localhost:8080/ToDoListProj" method="get">
         <input title="Register" type="submit" value="Not Yet A Member?" formaction="register.jsp"/>
        <br/>
    </form>
    </section>
</body>
```

and this is the controller:

```
package il.ac.hit.controller;

import il.ac.hit.model.HibernateToDoListDAO;
import il.ac.hit.model.Item;
import il.ac.hit.model.ToDoListPlatformException;
import il.ac.hit.model.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import antlr.StringUtils;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ToDoListPlatformContrller
 */
@WebServlet("/controller/*")
public class ToDoListPlatformController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ToDoListPlatformController() {
        super();

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    private boolean isAlphaNumeric(String word)
    {
        return word.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String path = request.getPathInfo();
        System.out.println(path);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;

        switch(path)
        {
        case "/login":
        {
            try {
                String username = request.getParameter("username");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                if(username != null && password != null && isAlphaNumeric(username) && isAlphaNumeric(password))
                {
                    List<User> usersList = il.ac.hit.model.HibernateToDoListDAO.getInstance().getUsersList();
                    for(User user : usersList)
                    {
                        if(user.getName().equals(username) && user.getPassword().equals(password))
                        {
                            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("UserId", username);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                            request.getSession().setAttribute("UserID", username);
                            request.getSession().setAttribute("table", HibernateToDoListDAO.getInstance().getItemsList(username));
                            dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp");
                            break;
                        }   
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/wronglogin.jsp");
                }

            } catch (ToDoListPlatformException e) {

                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/wronglogin.jsp");
            }

            break;
        }

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

when I enter a username and password on the login jsp page and hit submit, both attributes are being shown in the URL line.

this is what I get:

```
http://localhost:8080/ToDoListProj/controller/login?username=usernamesample&password=passwordasmple
```

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 2):

You should change `method="get"` to `method="post"`.

`GET` method adds the data to the URL as in your case. Never use `get` method when deals with auth. forms.

Answer (score 0):

Use Http POST instead of GET:

In the JSP

```
<form name="login" action="controller/login" method="post"
```

and in the controller:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    // read login data from request like you do now in doGet...
```

Comment: thank you, it worked.
now i have another prob.
after login, the servlet forward the url to view.jsp witch is a view of items.
there is an "add item" button.
after i add an item it goes back to the view page and show it in a list.
but if i hit 'refresh' the item is being added again.

Comment: @Dan the refresh triggers the "add item" action again. There is a pattern to deal with this problem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.

Answer (score 0):

`<form name="login" action="controller/login" method="get"` , the form uses get ,so the parameters show up in the url ,use `method="post"`. Now remember after making this `doPost()` will be called , so ou'll have to either copy your code in to `doPost()` or call `doGet()` from `doPost()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `get` to `post` method

```
 <form name="login" action="controller/login" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

> In `get` the request parameters are passed to the server by appending
>   at the end of the url, whereas in a post request form elements or
>   parameters are passed as a part of HTTP body and does not append at
>   the end of URL. So whenever we need to send some sensitive information
>   to server, a `post` request is sent.

Answer (score 0):

HttpGet is "OK", if you use https instead of http. Https will encrypt your get parameters (but the whole request url may be saved unencrypted in server logs for example, therefore HttpPost would be the method of choice).

In addition to all the answers saying you should use `method=post`, you could put the code from `doGet` in a own function, lets say `login`, so you can use HttpPost and HttpGet at the same time:

```
private RequestDispatcher login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String path = request.getPathInfo();
    System.out.println(path);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;

    switch(path)
    {
    case "/login":
    {
        try {
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            if(username != null && password != null && isAlphaNumeric(username) && isAlphaNumeric(password))
            {
                List<User> usersList = il.ac.hit.model.HibernateToDoListDAO.getInstance().getUsersList();
                for(User user : usersList)
                {
                    if(user.getName().equals(username) && user.getPassword().equals(password))
                    {
                        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("UserId", username);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("UserID", username);
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("table", HibernateToDoListDAO.getInstance().getItemsList(username));
                        dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp");
                        break;
                    }   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/wronglogin.jsp");
            }

        } catch (ToDoListPlatformException e) {

            dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/wronglogin.jsp");
        }

        break;
    }

    return dispatcher;  
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    login(request, response).forward(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    login(request, response).forward(request, response);
}
```